# Implications of transferring AWS EC2 t2.medium instance to EC2 t2.micro instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an AWS ec2 ubuntu 18.04 t2.medium account and I no longer need the resources, so I'd like to transfer my instance to an t2.micro account. It originally was an t2.micro account that i moved up to t2.medium.

My question is, I have sensitive data on the instance. I believe it started with 30GB. Will this data be compromised if i do the transfer and are there any other implications that I should be aware of by doing this transfer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T2 instances don’t have *instance storage* (aka *ephemeral storage*) so presumably all your data are on EBS volumes. That makes it easy - you can simply **Stop** the instance (*do not Terminate* it!!) and **Change the instance type** to t2.micro.

At this point I would also **Create an Image** from the instance - it will act as your backup image (AMI) in case you ever need to restore it.

Then you can **Start** the instance again. However you said that you don’t need it at the moment - you can leave it in *Stopped state* for as long as you want and not pay for any compute time at all and only pay a few cents for the EBS storage. You can start and stop it again whenever needed.

You can also use something like [EC2 Start-Stop](https://github.com/mludvig/ec2-start-stop) if you want to schedule the instance to run e.g. only during business hours instead of 24/7 and save some more on compute time.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Will it affect my Route53 settings? Also, i am having issues finding pricing on creating a backup template

Comment: @JonathanKushner does the instance have a *Public IP* or *Elastic IP* address? Public IP changes when you stop/start the EC2, Elastic IP doesn’t. Private IP stays the same. That in turn answers whether you Route53 record will need to be updated.

Comment: Yes it has a public ip so it will change. what about the pricing on a backup template?

Comment: @JonathanKushner With AMI you only pay for the storage used. It’s described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18661365

Comment: Elastic IPs are static IPs, which are best for servers. Note that they have a small cost if they're allocated to your account but not attached to a running server.